# MS Access - Expression not identifying contents of combo box?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am very new to MS Access and am trying to get an expression in a query to use the selected text in a combo box, however when I run the query a blank is returned for the selected field. The intention is for the user to be able to select an option from the drop down list in the combo box and then press a button to run the query to bring up all info on that option. The expression is as follows:

```
[Forms]![Policy_Interactions_Form]![PA1Combo]
```

What could be causing the expression to return blank values when I can see a selected value in the combo box?

When viewing the query in SQL view it looks like this:

```
SELECT Policy_Interactions.[Policy Area 1], Policy_Interactions.[Policy Area 2], Policy_Interactions.Interaction, *

FROM Policy_Interactions

WHERE (((Policy_Interactions.[Policy Area 1])=[Forms]![Policy_Interactions_Form]![PA1Combo]) AND ((Policy_Interactions.[Policy Area 2])=[Forms]![Policy_Interactions_Form]![PA2Combo]));
```

Comment: Your argument/criteria passing seems okay. Based on data type of table field you need single quote `'`, hash `#` etc. Please post your query here.

Comment: The data type of the field to be selected via the combo box is short text. Forgive my inexperience but I'm not entirely sure where I would need to add a single quote ', hash # etc. though, please could you explain a little further?

Comment: Edit your question and post your query so that we can suggest.

Comment: I have now edited the post to include the SLQ query, is that right?